# Sharing file handles across worker threads in node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, file, worker

In very simple term i have an application which appends to file post doing some compute, to speed up this i broke the operation in chuncks equal to worker threads available to me so that each can run the compute and purge it to disk, since they are going to append to the same file can i open the file handle on main thread and pass it to the worker threads or i have to open same file on all worker threads?